# how to save page source in a php variable?

Tags: php, html

i have an html email being generated by certain php functions and collected from several tables in the database and organized in an html layout..right now it is all in a preview.php page for testing the layout but when i need to send it to subscribers, i need to get the html code generated from this page only,and send that code in an email.and i mean by page source the one i see when i right click on the page and then click view source..so how do i get this page source ? or save it into a certain variable to use it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Use file_get_contents(), since it returns the file in a string:

`$html = file_get_contents('preview.php')`

Your whole html is now saved in the `$html` variable as a string.

**Option 2:**

If your preview.php contains some PHP processing, you can do this instead (so that the PHP codes get executed, and you still get the resulting html):

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
include('preview.php');
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Again, your whole html is now saved in the `$html` variable as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should generate your html with PHP and then save it in a session variable before echoing it.

Something like

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<-- Here you have the full html of the page -->
</html>
HTML;
session_start();
$_SESSION['html'] = $html;
echo $html;
```

Then when you want to send the email you simply do

```
$message = $_SESSION['html'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want looks a bit weird to me (why not get it into a variable instead of echoing it?)
Anyway, have a look to the ob_start & [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) functions

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to have preview.php do this:

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<div>';
$html .= 'Text within div';
$html .= '</div>';
// etc
echo $html;
// Do other stuff with $html
```

But if you just want the lazy way, leaving preview.php doing echo statements, do this:

```
ob_start();
// Make the HTML using echo
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thank you all ! i tried the right way but it didn't work, .there is something i didn't get, what do i put within the div? i dont have just text, i have tables and data echoed by php , you mean i should remove the html tag and start my layout directly? . i actually used the lazy way using ob_start() and ob_get_contents() but would be happy to do it the right way !

Comment: If you just replace every 'echo' with '$html .=' then you should find it works. If preview.php is including other files, this may get complex as you would have to do the same in the other files too. No real problem doing it the lazy way if it works though :)